# How to update child node in firebase databasae using querybase (with some additional values)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using querybase to insert some record in firebase database that works very fine. i.e

```
const databaseRef = firebase.database().ref().child('bookingsearchlist');
const querybaseRef = querybase.ref(databaseRef, ['createdat', 'referenceno', 'categoryname']);

querybaseRef.push({
referenceno:referenceno,
bookingcategoryname: categoryname,
bookinglocation2: location2,
createdat: getDateFromUnixTimeStamp_Formatted(createdat, "yyyy/MM/dd"),
genericinfo: genericinfo,
priority: priority,
});
```

This works fine till now. Now I'm going to update same node with some additional parameters or values. But it didn't update any record and insert a separate new childnode. i.e

```
const databaseRef = firebase.database().ref().child('bookingsearchlist/'+mainkey);

const querybaseRef = querybase.ref(databaseRef, ['callsign', 'createdat', referenceno']);

querybaseRef.push({
    dispatchid:newDispatchKey,
    callsign: bookinglistDataObject.callsign,
    crewnamecsv: bookinglistDataObject.crewnamecsv,
    dispatchtime: bookinglistDataObject.dispatchtime,
    droplocation2: droplocation2,
    droplocationname: bookinglistDataObject.droplocationname,
    qualification: bookinglistDataObject.qualification,
    status: bookinglistDataObject.status,
    statustime: bookinglistDataObject.statustime,
    referenceno: referenceno,
    bookingcategoryname: globalunitdispatchlistDataObject.bookingcategoryname,
    bookinglocation2: globalunitdispatchlistDataObject.bookinglocation2,
    createdat: getDateFromUnixTimeStamp_Formatted(globalunitdispatchlistDataObject.createdat, "yyyy/MM/dd"),
    genericinfo: globalunitdispatchlistDataObject.genericinfo,
    priority: globalunitdispatchlistDataObject.priority
});
```

**my Database**

[image]

Comment: To update an existing node, call `ref.update` on it: https://github.com/davideast/Querybase/blob/cd49bfa7756adeec62dca4d8780702069349e128/src/querybase.ts#L123